# android accessibility clickable with 2 fingers

Tags: android, html, web

I want to know why there are some 'elements' that are clickable only with 2 fingers, and how can I make that it will be clicked only with one.

Answer (score 0):

All touch screens are clickable with a single finger. Even the keyboard if you want or you can use two fingers or one finger. With one finger, however, is not allowed to zoom in on images, there are obligatory two fingers